# Explain maven javadoc plugin empty <p> tag error

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build javadocs for my project and it gives me following error:

```
 [ERROR] /home/kshitiz/Documents/workspaces/ggts/log4j-weblayout/src/main/java/in/ksharma/weblayout/WebAppender.java:25: warning: empty <p> tag
 [ERROR] * <p>
 [ERROR] ^
 [ERROR] /home/kshitiz/Documents/workspaces/ggts/log4j-weblayout/src/main/java/in/ksharma/weblayout/WebAppender.java:30: error: unexpected end tag: </p>
```

The class in question has this Javadoc:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Appender to allow logging to multiple files. Utilizes the roll over and
 * appending functionality of the FileRollingAppender.
 * 
 * Exceptions are stored in small HTML file called snippet. We use several small
 * HTML files instead of one large one due to performance reasons.
 * </p>
 * 
 * <p>
 * <h1>Usage:</h1>
 * It supports the same set of configuration options as
 * <code>org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender</code> Consult log4j documentation
 * for full list of options.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author Kshitiz Sharma
 */
```

The

tag is not empty. What is wrong with this javadoc?

Comment: Wich line is line 25 and 30?

Comment: @Jens 25 is the `<p>` before `<h1>Usage:</h1>` and 30 is the corresponding closing tag.

Comment: Have tried to remove the inner tags (<h1>, <code>) to see if the plugin has a problem with it?

Comment: Move the `<h1>usage:</h1>` above the `<p>`.  Headings cannot be nested inside paragraphs. I think the `<code>` will be okay inside the paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is misleading. It says `<p>` is empty but the real issue is that it doesn't like `<h>` tags nested inside `<p>`.

If you want to emphasize text inside a paragraph try using `<em>` instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to like <ul> inside <p> either...maven 3.3.3, Eclipse Kepler, JDK 1.8.

Comment: This has a good explanation under the "Tag omission" session as to why the </p> error is occurring. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p